# jQuery UI autocomplete leaves randomly sized gray box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm currently getting more and more confused by jQuery's autocomplete feature.
With the suggestion box's first popup, a gray background box is created and remains after selecting a value.
It only disappears in re-rendered areas.
e.g. toggling a checkbox's state makes the gray box disappear withing the checkbox's bounding box.

I really cannot determine why or how this box appears, nor can I locate it's color's definition.

Here's my code for initializing the autocomplete feature:

```
$('#inputsubstance')
.autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: schadstoffliste,
    focus: function() {
        return false;
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        this.value = ui.item.label + " (" + ui.item.cas + ")";
        return false;
    }
}).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul,item){
    return $("<li></li>")
    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
    .append("<a><strong>"+item.label+"</strong> / "+item.cas+" - "+item.value+"</a>")
    .appendTo(ul);
};
```

I'm using the smootheness theme and I'm developing for phonegap on iPad.
Unfortunately I can't test on a desktop browser right now, since I'm using phonegap's File API. But this happened on desktop as well, at least in Chrome.

EDIT:

On desktop browsers the overlay does NOT appear - somehow tricked myself.
The overlay seems to be the iPad's automatically generated overlay, shown when the keyboard appears.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle?

Comment: Hence there's quite some sensitive data inside the app, unfortunately I can't. Meanwhile I managed to rebuild a desktop-version, where this overlay doesn't appear against my thoughts. This overlay-stuff seems to belong to iPad's kayboard overlay